# assign string from list

Tags: c#, string

I've created a list with a lot of options, let's say for every character a different color.

```
string A = "#FFB97FC9";
string B = "#FF9BCC50";
// etc.
string answer1 = Options.Answer1;
answerRectangle.Fill = GetColorFromHexa(answer1);
```

now let's say that `Options.Answer1 = A`.

I want `answerRectangle` to have the color from the code `#FFB97FC9`

How can I achieve this?

**NOTE: I want to have `answer1 = #FFB97FC9`**

Comment: Please clarify a bit.

Comment: -1 The title should be "Assign color from hex value"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a dictionary with options:

```
Dcitionary<string, string> colors = new Dictionary<string, string>();
colors.Add("A", "#FFB97FC9");
colors.Add("B", "#FF9BCC50");
```

and then:

```
answerRectangle.Fill = GetColorFromHexa(colors[answer1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary instead of variables:

```
var colors = new Dictionary<string, string>();
colors["A"] = "#FFB97FC9";
colors["B"] = "#FF9BCC50";
// etc.
string answer1 = Options.Answer1;
answerRectangle.Fill = GetColorFromHexa(colors[answer1]);
```